# How do I reference a variable from one class to another?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, reference

I'm new to C# and I can't figure out how to reference the value of a variable from one class to another.

It's set to when the button is pressed, it'll take the text in the text box and sets that as "alphaask". Then it instances "alphaanswer" which would tell the label to change its text.

"alphaanswer" will take the value "alphaQuest" and see if its equal to "bob" which then would change the label.

ALL I want to know how to set the value of "alphaQuest" from the value of "alphaask" so the string can check it with "alphaanswer"

```
public partial class QuestionTab : Form
{
    public string alphaask = "null";

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // alphabutton
        // Checks if something is in textbox then says bool is true
        bool asked = false;
        if(textBoxAlpha.Text != "")
        {
            alphaask = textBoxAlpha.Text;
            asked = true;
        }

        if(asked==true)
        {

            // If bool is true than instance auxy
            var instance = new Alpha();
            instance.alphaanswer();

        }
    }
}

public class Alpha
{
    string alphaQuest = // <-- I want to make alphaQuest equal to alphaask

    alphaanswer();

    public void alphaanswer()
    {
        if (alphaanswer == bob)
         {
          //change text in label1
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could change your method alphaanswer to accept one string parameter, and pass alphaask variable -> public void alphaanswer(string answer) ... instance.alphaanswer(alphaask );

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61943591/edit) the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943591/how-to-reference-variable-from-different-class) with more details, or address the comments from that question (in the form of "more details") in *this* question. What are you trying to do? Your question does not contain enough information to provide an answer. You can access fields of class "A" from another class by creating (or passing) an instance of class "A". But that does not provide an answer for the real question, which is: "what are you trying to do?"

Comment: You can set or get the value of another class by using an instance of the class and dot. Ex you could do instance.alphaQuest = alphaanswer (you may need to make alphaquest public)... but if you are going down that path you want to use properties ex public string AlphaQuest {get; set;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these changes

```
public partial class QuestionTab : Form
{
    public string alphaask = "null";

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool asked = false;
        if(textBoxAlpha.Text != "")
        {
            alphaask = textBoxAlpha.Text;
            asked = true;
        }

        if(asked==true)
        {

            // If bool is true than instance auxy
            var instance = new Alpha();
            instance.alphaAnswer(alphaask); 
            //Here you are sending the current value of alphaAsk to the alphaanswer method.
        }
    }
}


public class Alpha
{
    public void alphaAnswer(string alphaAnswer) //This string receives the value you sent
    {
        if (alphaAnswer == "bob")
         {
          //change text in label1
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a contractor in class Alpha with String parameter

```
public Alpha(String value)
{
}
```

then when you call it

```
var instance = new Alpha(alphaask);
instance.show();
```

Comment: Does `Alpha` have a `Show` method? It's not shown in the code.